# MySQL 5 on Mac 10.5: "problem connecting to the database"

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x, errors

I have worked with MySQL for years but I am stuck on a seemingly trivial problem.

I installed MySQL 5.0.96 on Mac 10.5, created a database, created a user with privileges on everything, and problem:
Apache/PHP (osCommerce) installed on the **same machine** says:

```
There was a problem connecting to the database server. The following error had occured:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
Please verify the connection parameters and try again.
```

It is my first time installing MySQL on Mac, and there might be a bug with `%`, so I added for all addresses I could imagine (%, localhost, 127.0.0.1, my IP) but no luck:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'192.168.43.152' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'192.168.43.152' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Default install, I did not change any parameter.
`skip_networking` is `OFF`.
The Mac firewall is set to accept anything.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem:
Somehow, MySQL decided to create `mysql.sock` in `/private/tmp` rather than in `/var/mysql`.

So, my solution was to create a symlink:

```
cd /var
sudo mkdir mysql
sudo ln -s /private/tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

Now everything works fine.